# JSP - when use directives and when jsp tags?

Tags: java, jsp

For example, consider you want forward user to another page.
Which solution is better?

```
<%@ page forward = "anotherPage.jsp" %>
```

or

```
<jsp:forward page = "anotherPage.jsp" %>
```

In this case, I really can't find any differences between them.

Comment: OMG. Is there a directive @forward ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, forwarding to another page shouldn't be done from a JSP. That's a responsibility of the controller, which should be written in Java (as a servlet, or action of your preferred MVC controller).

Now to answer your question: there is no forward directive. So you can't use it. The only existing directives are `page`, `include` and `taglib`. See http://careerride.com/JSP-directives.aspx (for example) for additional details.